# Javascript persistence > logic

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please help me find a solution that uses plain 'ol javascript (I cannot use external frameworks). Also, CSS :hover selector won't work for the real world implementation.

Somethings going on with the registered event sets all calling the last registered events array item.

```
<body>
        <p>When you hover over &lt;div&gt; tags 0-2, that &lt;div&gt; tag should highlight in red. Why do all of the &lt;div&gt; tags only affect the last &lt;div&gt;?</p>

        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>

        <p>The same results for &lt;p&gt; tags.</p>

        <p class="test"></p>
        <p class="test"></p>
        <p class="test"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //create arrays
            var divArr = new Array();
            var pArr = new Array();

            //call function to populate arrays
            divArr = getElementsByClassName('div','test');
            pArr = getElementsByClassName('p','test');

            //call function to register arrays elements events
            registerArrayElementsEvents(divArr,'div');
            registerArrayElementsEvents(pArr,'p');

            //retrieve elements that match the passed tag and class
            function getElementsByClassName(myTag,myClass) {
                //load all elements into array
                var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(myTag);
                //create new array placeholder
                var newArr = new Array();

                //iterate through elements array
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    //check to see if element class matches parameter
                    if (elems[i].className == myClass){
                        //add matched element to new array
                        newArr.push(elems[i]);
                    }
                }

                //return array of matched elements
                return newArr;
            }

            //register events to every element in the passed array
            function registerArrayElementsEvents(arr,type){
                //create object placeholder
                var currentObj = new Object();

                //iterate through the objects array
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    //assign current object corresponding to loop counter

                    currentObj = arr[i];

                    //write element index to element
                    currentObj.innerHTML = 'This is &lt;' + type + '&gt; ' + i;

                    //add mouseover event to element
                    addEvent(currentObj,'mouseover',function(){
                        //set current element color to red
                        currentObj.style.color = '#f00'
                    });

                    //add mouseout event to element
                    addEvent(currentObj,'mouseout',function(){
                        //set current element color to black
                        currentObj.style.color = '#000'
                    });
                }
            }

            //register functions to events for objects
            function addEvent(obj,evt,fn){
                //if not IE
                        if (obj.addEventListener)
                    obj.addEventListener(evt,fn,false);
                //if IE
                else if (obj.attachEvent)
                    obj.attachEvent('on'+evt,fn);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: First, be polite when asking for help, second, ask an actual question rather than a vague "something is going on". If you have constraints, state them.

Comment: Frankly I don't get why you can't use jQuery. It's practically mandatory for Javascript development these days (Or at least a jQuery equivalent)

Comment: @Codemonkey - I'd give you a +1 but I can't find a jQuery plugin to do that...

Comment: You have problems with closures, see e.g. http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: @Codemonkey I loath you for saying that. Not only is it wrong fundamentally but ideologically too. JQUERY IS NOT GOOD CODE. Its a minimalistic JavaScript _WRAPPER_ for script kiddies who are unable to write their own. jQuery promotes bad programming. BEWARE.

Comment: @Greg Agnew: As far as I can tell jQuery is not a "JavaScript wrapper" at all--it works entirely with the DOM. This is great if you're in the browser but completely useless if you're using node.js or the like. It would be nice not to equate JavaScript and the DOM.

Comment: @Tikhon - I think he meant that it is written in javascript and wraps DOM elements. Also, JavaScript (tm) started life as DOM scripting, then moved to ECMAScript + DOM. It has become ECMAScript in a host environment and so has moved beyond browsers (and documents). But the OP is very much about HTML documents, so in this case it really is about the DOM.

Comment: @Greg: My point was that jQuery dealt with the _DOM_ rather than with JavaScript--it is not a wrapper, nor a replacement for the _language_ but rather a wrapper for the horrible api that is the DOM. The DOM is _not_ inherent in JavaScript; they are two separate entities. To reiterate: JavaScript and the DOM are practically orthogonal and jQuery only deals with the latter. Regarding the _ad hominem_: I am actually one of the crazy people who uses JavaScript on the server where jQuery doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that in `currentObj` in `registerArrayElementsEvents` is scoped to `registerArrayElementsEvents` rather than each event's function. You need to put `currentObj` into each function's scope as so:

```
addEvent(currentObj, 'mouseover', (function (obj) {
    return function () { 
        obj.style.color = '#f00';
    };
})(currentObj));
```

Basically, JavaScript only scopes based on functions, not on blocks. This means that

```
for (...) { var x = arr[i] }
```

is exactly the same as:

```
var x;
for (...) {x = arr[i]}
```

This means that after the loop is done, `x` is set to the last element of the array. If you referenced `x` in a function, when it goes to look `x` after the loop is done (like after an event) it gets the newest value of `x`. To overcome this, you can create a closure each time you loop through by using an anonymous function like I did.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         //create arrays
>         var divArr = new Array();
>         var pArr = new Array();
>
>         //call function to populate arrays
>         divArr = getElementsByClassName('div','test');
>         pArr = getElementsByClassName('p','test');
> ```

By assigning new values to `divArr` and `pArr` you over write the arrays originally assigned. That isn't your issue, it just means the original assignment is useless.

TIkhon has one answer, another way is to avoid the closure with `this`:

```
addEvent(currentObj, 'mouseover', function () {
        this.style.color = '#f00';
    });
```

but you will have to modify the `addEvent` function for `attachEvent` so set `this` correctly. I'll add that shortly...